# How does an almost complex structure on a sphere determine a 1-fold cross product?

Tags: manifolds, spheres, cross-product, almost-complex

In the article "**VECTOR CROSS PRODUCTS ON MANIFOLDS**", by *Alfred Gray*, the author states, between theorem 2.8 and corollary 2.9, that

> The existence of vector cross product of Type I [1-fold vector cross product] on spheres is the well-known problem of the existence of almost complex structures on spheres.

How can I see this? I need specifically to show that the existence of an almost complex structure on a sphere determines a 1-fold vector cross product on the same sphere. Does anyone know where I can find the answer?

**Edit 1**: Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over the real numbers and let $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ be a nondegenerate bilinear form on $V$. A 1-fold vector cross product is a linear map $P:V \rightarrow V$ such that
\begin{equation}
\langle P(v), v \rangle = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\lVert P(v) \rVert^2 = \lVert v \rVert^2.
\end{equation}

Let $J$ be the almost complex structure. Since $J^2 = -Id$, the idea is to associate $J$ with a rotation of $\pi/2$ radians. But $J$ is not that well behaved, and so it has to be corrected to keep the norm and be orthogonal. In any Euclidean space of even dimension it is easy to fix $J$. But in the sphere the situation is different: this fix has to vary continuously as the base point of the space tangent to the sphere varies.

It might be of some help (or not): if $J$ preserves norm, $(J+I)(v)$ is orthogonal to $v$, but $J+I$ fails to preserve norm.

Comment: What did you try to solve this?

Comment: What *is* a 1-fold cross product, precisely?

Comment: Thanks for the interaction! I edited my post to respond to your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, the definition of a cross-product requires a  choice of a Riemannian metric on the given manifold. The correct reading of Gray's statement is:

> Suppose that $(M,J)$ is an almost complex manifold. Then there exists a Riemannian metric $h$ on $M$ (one can take any metric Hermitian with respect to $J$), such that $J$ yields a 1-fold cross-product on $(M,h)$.

In order to prove this, first note that every almost complex structure $J$ on a manifold $M$ (the exact topology of $M$ is irrelevant here) has a compatible Hermitian metric $h$. Next, let $u$ be a nonzero vector in $T_xM$. Then $u$ and $Ju$ span a real 2-dimensional subspace $V(u)$ in $T_xM$. The condition that $J^2=-Id$ and the assumption that   $J$ preserves $h$, implies that $J$ acts as an order $4$ rotation in $V(u)$. Hence, $Ju$ is orthogonal to $u$ and has the same norm as $u$. Thus, the map
$$
u\mapsto Ju
$$
is a 1-fold cross-product with respect to the metric $h$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
In Theorem 2.8, Gray defines $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ as "the metric tensor of $S^n$ induced from the usual positive definite one on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$", so I thought the metric was fixed. But in fact, the demonstration does not depend on the metric and so it makes a lot of sense to change the metric to a well-behaved one.

Comment: Another curious down-vote on a correct answer...